# How are streams (OOP) represented on the assembly level?

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, java-stream, rx-java

How are streams like Java's Stream API or RxJava represented on the assembly level?

I.E.

```
List<String> myList =
    Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1");

myList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It's more appropriate to ask how objects and methods are represented. When you understand those - and they're big topics - then you understand streams because that's what they're built from. Consider getting a good book on compiler construction. SO is not the best place to attempt to learn what would be covered by an entire undergrad CS course.

Comment: Java streams are not a language feature. They are standard Java code, written as standard classes and methods. There is nothing special about them. The stream class has an operation pipeline and many of its methods (non-terminal methods) just memorize the operation you want to execute in that pipeline. And as soon as you have a terminal operation it will simply iterate over the data set (possibly multi-threaded) and apply the operation pipeline in order on each element. Thats it.

Comment: Sure you are asking about the stream api and not, maybe, the lambdas or the method references? Because those two are the only language features here. Streams are just standard Java methods and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very complex topic to cover in a few sentences. You can start researching from [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/) by [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) to understand concept of Java Stream API. After that you'll be able to easily go deeper.

First of all take a closer look at Spliterator abstraction:

> A stream source is described by an abstraction called Spliterator. As its name suggests, Spliterator combines two behaviors: accessing the elements of the source (iterating), and possibly decomposing the input source for parallel execution (splitting).

Then take a look at Stream flags :

> In the internal representation, each stage of the pipeline is described by a bitmap of stream flags that describe what’s known about the elements at this stage of the stream pipeline. Streams uses these flags to optimize both the construction and execution of the stream.

and execution of Stream pipeline

> When the terminal operation is initiated, the stream implementation picks an execution plan.
>
> For sequential execution, Streams constructs a “machine” — a chain of Consumer objects whose structure matches that of the pipeline structure. Each of these Consumer objects knows about the next stage; when it receives an element (or is notified that there are no more elements), it sends zero or more elements to the next stage in the chain.

And then you'll be able to find out how each of intermediate and terminal operations represented at assemble level.